# Last update about Europe in the Shadowrun canon

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun, shadowrun-anarchy

I know there was [Shadows of Europe](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shadows-Europe-Shadowrun-Fanpro/dp/1932564101), published by Fanpro in 2003, but that was (omg) fourteen years, two full editions, and (at least) one publisher ago. (I'm not sure about the number of publishers, because I haven't been actively following the fate of SR for quite a while.)

**Where online / in what printed publication can I find the latest and most detailed canonical update about the current state of Europe in the world of Shadowrun, updating the content of 3rd ed. SoE?**

Answer (score 3):

You can find some recent information on European countries in the [Sixth World Almanac](http://shadowrun.wikia.com/wiki/Source:Sixth_World_Almanac). The date is 2072, so nearly up to date for 5th edition. Although the information is *very sparse*: nothing about Europe in general and one to two pages about some countries (France, UK and Germany if I recall correctly, might be some more).

Answer (score 3):

This French books (about SOX and France) are canon : [SOX](https://www.black-book-editions.fr/produit.php?id=56) and [Néo-Révolution](https://www.black-book-editions.fr/produit.php?id=6545).

Comment: Yup, Shadowrun has a long history of publishing Europe-specific books only in European languages. German is particularly noteworthy as having a lot more material than other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single book with a concentrated block of information on Europe in SR4, but there are a few bits here and there, ***Sixth World Almanac*** has been mentioned, ***Corporate Enclaves***, ***Corporate Guide***, ***Feral Cities***, and ***Runner Havens*** all have some Eurocentric information as do some of the adventure/mission books including ***Artifacts*** and ***London Falling***. There's also a little bit in the Fall of a Dragon chapter of ***Storm Front*** and a History Lesson for the Reality Impaired in the ***Shadowrun: 20th Anniversary Core Rulebook***. ***Euro War Antiques*** has a lot of history for the region that I don't believe had been published previously and finally and probably least helpfully ***Parazoology 2*** has a very little material on SOX. Sorry I don't know what may or may not be in SR5.